# Interacting Quantum Fields in Curved Spacetime

Tags: metric-tensor, standard-model, higgs, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was thinking this night that how would the fields interaction or the vacuum expectation value of Higgs field changes when spacetime is not flat? 
e.g., the higgs field interact with the electron field to give mass to the electron, but what would happen to the interaction or to the vacuum expectation value of Higgs field if spacetime is not flat. 
Please explain the possible answer by considering this interacting fields case.
Also, i think for such cases we need a Quantum gravity theory that can accommodate gravity with QFT.
Feel free to answer the question at any level.

Comment: You can hope to address this question without quantum gravity. QFT in curved space is usually studied semiclassically, without quantum gravity... I expect the answer to your questions will be, very small quantum corrections to the flat-space behavior; except in conditions of *very* strong curvature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the fields interaction change on those cases is something you'd find in a [quantum field theory in curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime). One of the consequences is that what looks like a vacuum to one observer cannot look like a vacuum state to another observer, for example.

Answer (score 0):

First, electrons are point particles, elementary particles, with fixed invariant mass.

In SR, the invariant mass comes from the length of the four vector.

In the standard model, the Higgs mechanism gives mass to the particles at weak symmetry breaking.

All the particles (elementary) are described by the field that exists in all of spacetime. The vacuum expectation value of these fields is all zero. Except the Higgs field. This is a part of the mechanism that gave mass to the elementary particles.

You are saying that the electron gains mass because the electron field interacts with the Higgs field, you write this like it happens all the time, whenever they are interacting. This is a common misconception.

Symmetry breaking happened once, and at that point all the elementary particles gained mass. You write this like this is an interaction, and every time the electron has to gain mass. But it is not right. This happened at some point once, and since all the elementary particles have their (rest) masses.

Comment: The electron *does* have its mass by virtue of constant interaction with the Higgs field. The only reason its mass is constant is because the Higgs vev is constant.

Comment: @Arpad Szendrei

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -4):

The Higgs field doesn't give mass to the electron. It's responsible for giving mass to the gauge bosons of the electroweak force through spontaneous symmetry breaking.

However, not all of them gain mass. The U(1) gauge boson remains massless as it becomes the photon but the gauge bosons of weak force, the W particles are given mass.

Comment: The Higgs field does give mass to the electron (and all the other elementary fermions of the standard model, except the neutrinos), through the yukawa coupling.

Comment: @mitchell porter: Thanks for your correction - my mistake.